# Whonix/Tor Connecting Error

Tags: whonix, torcheck

The day before I got a serious problem communicating with Tor.

Tor Bootstrap Result:
Whonix-check gave up waiting after 60 seconds.
Bootstrapping 85% done.

Tor reports: WARN BOOTSRAP PROGRESS=85 TAG= handshake_or SUMMARY="Finishing handshake with first
hop “WARNING="Connection timed out" REASON=TIMEOUT COUNT=75 RECOMMENDATION=warn

[image]

First of all I checked the Tor on host and Tor working well, but before ruining showed me this :

```
    7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec Tor\PluggableTransports\fteproxy --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (fte exec Tor\PluggableTransports\fteproxy --managed) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.587 [NOTICE] Pluggable transport proxy (flashproxy exec Tor\PluggableTransports\flashproxy-client --register :0 :9000) does not provide any needed transports and will not be launched. 
7/29/2014 7:33:11 AM.615 [NOTICE] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying directory fetches again. 
7/29/2014 7:33:13 AM.771 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server. 
7/29/2014 7:33:13 AM.778 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. 
7/29/2014 7:33:15 AM.375 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. 
7/29/2014 7:33:15 AM.803 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus. 
7/29/2014 7:33:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 50%: Loading relay descriptors. 
7/29/2014 7:33:35 AM.159 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 208.79.90.242:35658 ("TTL expired")
```

But after awhile Tor is connecting and Tor browser normally opens. However, I Still have problem connecting on Whonix OS.

Comment: Dear, do you use bridges or pluggable transport bridges?

Comment: I just used Whonix by default, I didn't nothing changed and about Tor on host (windows7) too nothing changed on it.

Comment: Why are you running Tor on the host? That's not necessary for running Whonix. And it may be the source of your problem. I don't have a Windows box to test on, and I don't remember how VirtualBox handles Tor running on the host. Anyway, see if Whonix works when Tor is NOT running on the host.

Comment: Yes I know it's not required to use Tor on host (windows7) for ruining whonix on VB. I am using to make sure it works. Until a few days ago, Whonix OS worked well. My main problem with this is that the Whonix OS is not connected to Tor any more.

Comment: I just tested on Whonix OS without Tor running on host, but it still does not work...

Comment: I'm living on censorship country how can I using and set the bridges on Whonix OS?

Comment: @Photon The first time that Whonix runs, it goes through the bridge dialog. Delete your Whonix VMs, and import again the appliance files that you downloaded.

Comment: I read this document. https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Bridges
Also I got picked up the obfs3 and obfs2 is required from here: https://bridges.torproject.org/options and the set on the /etc/tor/torrc.
There is no need for delete Whonix getaway and installing again. Just need a little bit patient and searching.

Comment: With last comment, everything is working well...

Comment: This question seems abandoned, thus I'll close it. If you have further information, please [edit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3661/88) the question and it can be reopened.